# How to produce a nullable property in the lightweight entity for a database view?

Tags: codefluent

My model contains the following entity:

```
<cf:entity name="SomeEntity">
  <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
  <cf:property name="SomeDate" typeName="date?" />

  <cf:view name="SomeEntitySummary" autoLightweight="true" checkLevel="none">
    <cf:viewProperty name="Id" />
    <cf:viewProperty name="SomeDate" nullable="true" typeName="date?" />
  </cf:view>
</cf:entity>
```

The produced code for the SomeEntity class contains a SomeDate property of type

```
Nullable<DateTime>
```

However, the produced code for the SomeEntitySummary class contains a SomeDate property of type DateTime and is not nullable.

How can I produce a nullable property in the lightweight entity that is produced for the database view?

Answer (score 0):

CodeFluent Entities infer views from the properties of the entity. So, if the property is nullable, the property of the view should also be nullable. However, it seems there is a small issue, so you must declare the property as `modelNullable` explicitly (the modeler generates the right xml).

The following model does generate a `DateTime?` property in the `SomeView` class:

```
<cf:entity name="Customer">
  <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
  <cf:property name="Name" />
  <cf:property name="SomeDate" modelNullable="true" typeName="date" />

  <cf:view autoLightweight="true" name="SomeView">
    <cf:viewProperty name="Id" />
    <cf:viewProperty name="SomeDate" />
  </cf:view>
</cf:entity>
```